# How to calculate unbiased higher central co-moments?

Tags: statistics, expectation, estimation

Given four time series $W_i$, $X_i$, $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ for $i=1,2,3,...,T$ observations we define

$\bar W:= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^T w_i$, 
$\phantom{ff}$ $\bar X:= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^T x_i$,
$\phantom{ff}$ $\bar Y:= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^T y_i$,
$\phantom{ff}$ $\bar Z:= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^T z_i$

$m_n^W:= \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^T (w_i-\bar W)^n$ 
$\phantom{ffffffff}$ $m_n^X:= \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^T (x_i-\bar X)^n$ 
$\phantom{ffffffff}$ $m_n^Y:= \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^T (y_i-\bar Y)^n$
$\phantom{fffffffff}$ $m_n^Z:= \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^T (z_i-\bar Z)^n$

From standard statistics we know that for the variable $X$ the following holds:

$M_2^X=\frac{1}{T-1} \sum_{i=1}^T (x_i-\bar X)^2 = \frac{T}{T-1} m_2^X$ $\phantom{f}$ is an unbiased estimator for $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2]$

$M_3^X=\frac{T}{(T-1)(T-2)} \sum_{i=1}^T (x_i-\bar X)^3 = \frac{T^2}{(T-1)(T-2)} m_3^X$  is an unbiased estimator for $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^3]$

$M_4^X = \frac{T^2}{(T-2)(T-3)}\bigg(\frac{T+1}{T-1}m_4^X - 3(m_2^X)^2 \bigg) $ is an unbiased estimator for $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^4]$.

Now what would be an unbiased estimator for the central comoments

$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}(X))(Y-\mathbb{E}(Y))(Z-\mathbb{E}(Z))]$ $\phantom{ff}$

and especially for

$\mathbb{E}[(W-\mathbb{E}(W))(X-\mathbb{E}(X))(Y-\mathbb{E}(Y))(Z-\mathbb{E}(Z))]$?

I can't imagine the answer is just

$M_4^{WXYZ}=\frac{T}{(T-2)(T-3)} \sum_{i=1}^T (w_i-\bar W)(x_i-\bar X)(y_i-\bar Y)(z_i-\bar Z)$

**EDIT:**

The question has to do with the estimation of financial return moments. In finance you normally assume IID data and you calculate the sample Covariance matrix in the following way:$$\sigma_{ij} =\frac{1}{T-1} \sum_{i=1}^T (x_i-\bar X)(y_i-\bar Y)$$ for all $i,j$. 
As I know it is not necessary to assume a specific distribution.

Have a look at the Paper of Ledoit and Wolf.They do only assume IID Data: http://www.ledoit.net/ole2.pdf.
(Notice that Ledoit and Wolf define the sample estimator differently.)

Answer (score 2):

> Question: what would be an unbiased estimator for the central comoments
>   $$\mathbb{E}\big[ \; (X-\mathbb{E}[X]) \; (Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]) \; (Z-\mathbb{E}[Z]) \;\big]$$

**Answer**: You seek the multivariate $h$-statistic  $h_{a,b,c}$ which, by definition, is an unbiased estimator of the trivariate central moment $\mu_{a,b,c}$. That is:

$$\mathbb{E}[h_{a,b,c}] = \mu _{a,b,c}  \quad \text{where} \quad \mu _{a,b,c}=\mathbb{E}\big[ \; (X-\mathbb{E}[X])^a \; (Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^b \; (Z-\mathbb{E}[Z])^c \;\big]$$

In your case, $\{a,b,c\}=\{1,1,1\}$.

That's the easy part. The difficult part is the actual calculation of the $h$-statistics. Doing this by hand is fraught with computational difficulties and the literature is peppered with published results that are incorrect.

This problem can be solved using the `HStatistic` function in the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* which automates the calculation.

For your first problem, the h-statistic $h_{1,1,1}$ is:

[image]

where each trivariate power sum $s_{a,b,c}$ is defined by:

$$s_{a,b,c} =\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^a \; Y_i^b \;  Z_i^c$$

and $n$ is the sample size (your $T$).

For the 4 variable case, the unbiased estimator you seek is:

[image]

While this may look complicated, given a data set and a computer, one can readily apply it. One can also operate symbolically on the estimator, for example to show that $\mathbb{E}[sol] = \mu_{1,1,1}$, where the expectation operator is just the $1^\text{st}$ Raw Moment of `sol`:

[image]

This has just calculated the mathematical expectation of the estimator `sol` derived above, and returned the product central moment $\mu_{1,1,1}$ .

**More detail**

There is an extensive discussion of such unbiased estimator problems in Chapter 7 of our book:

- Rose and Smith,  "*Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica*", Springer, NY

A free download of the written chapter is available here:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

which also includes references for further reading. I am not aware of any texts dealing with multivariate h-statistics. The closest you might find is the multivariate k-statistics in Chapter 13 of:

- Stuart and Ord (1994), *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics*

As disclosure, I should note that I am an author of the `HStatistic` function used above.